# jQuery Sorting Updates the Other List Ordering

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/VkghS/19/

After do sorting the bars, I want it automatically orders the color name as well.

Any helps would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/VkghS/24/

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be to also make the label tr's draggable/sortable.

Then trigger their corresponding drag/drop events when the bars are moved around.

Comment: Yes I've made the table to be sortable as well, but i have no idea how to trigger drag/drop event by sorting the bars. I have Serialize result from bars sorting, how to use that as the parameter of triggered drag/drop event?

Comment: @Jeaffrey:  change: function(event, ui) { //extract data as to which bar was sorted and then trigger }